# MultiLevel JavaScript Inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, library

I'm making an experiment on JS, trying to build a framework for OOP. It's called [Universe](https://github.com/josegomezr/universe/tree/64cf9c390fc1d273a0442c0a89c7e954faa67670).

The main purpose is to emulate a mini-universe, where classes are "created" with a defined behavior (prototype) and objects are created from those classes to provide data.

So far I managed to make inheritance work (although the `instanceof` operator doesn't work), but my inheritance looks horrible. I've like 6 hours trying to make it pretty, but I always get stuck on a huge line like

```
this.universe.classes.<ClassName>.prototype.fullName.call(this)
```

#### Excerpt from [index.js](https://github.com/josegomezr/universe/blob/64cf9c390fc1d273a0442c0a89c7e954faa67670/index.js)

```
// trimmed for brevity
var MoleculeClass = universe.createClass('Molecule', {
    fullName: function () {
        return this.universe.classes.Atom.prototype.fullName.call(this) + " -- new molecule name with atoms -> " + this.get('numberOfAtoms') + "\n";
    }
}, 'Atom');
```

How can I make this "parent call" look more natural? More like `this.parent.fullName` or something like that.

When I tried passing parent as a reference to parent class it worked nice on 1-level inheritance, on a 2-level (grandchild class) the middle (child class) throws me a *max call stack size exceeded* error.

#### The [BigBang.js](https://github.com/josegomezr/universe/blob/64cf9c390fc1d273a0442c0a89c7e954faa67670/bigbang.js) library

[is.js](https://github.com/josegomezr/universe/blob/64cf9c390fc1d273a0442c0a89c7e954faa67670/is.js) and [utils.js](https://github.com/josegomezr/universe/blob/64cf9c390fc1d273a0442c0a89c7e954faa67670/utils.js) are just convenient shortcuts; they may be changed for some library like [lodash.js](/questions/tagged/lodash.js).

```
var is = require('./is.js');
var utils = require('./utils.js');

module.exports = (function () {
    var Containers = {};
    var GProto = {
        get: function(k){
            return Containers[this.__objectId__][k];
        },
        set: function(k, v){
            Containers[this.__objectId__][k] = v;
        },
        init: function(ctorArgs){
            Containers[this.__objectId__] = utils.extend({}, Containers[this.__objectId__], ctorArgs);
        },
        id: function(){
            return this.__objectId__;
        }
    };  

    function Bigbang (config) {
        this.classes = {};
        this.inheritances = {};
        this.instances = {};
        this.handlers = {};
    };

    Bigbang.prototype = utils.extend({}, Bigbang.prototype, {
        createClass: function (className, newProto, inheritsFrom) {
            inheritsFrom = inheritsFrom || null;

            var newClass = function GClass(){};
            var parentClass = this.findClass(inheritsFrom);

            newClass.prototype = utils.extend({}, Object.create(parentClass ? parentClass.prototype : GProto), {
                __class__: className
            }, newProto);

            newClass.prototype.constructor = newClass;

            this.inheritances[className] = inheritsFrom;

            this.classes[className] = newClass;
            return this.createObject.bind(this, className);
        },
        findClass: function (className) {
            return utils.have(this.classes, className) ? this.classes[className] : undefined;
        },
        createObject: function (className, ctorArgs) {
            var classToBe = this.findClass(className);

            var uid = utils.uniqueId('object_');
            var instance = new classToBe();

            instance.__objectId__ = uid;

            instance.universe = this;

            Containers[uid] = {};

            instance.init(ctorArgs);

            return instance;
        }
    });

    return Bigbang;
})();
```

#### Little Explanation

**`CreateClass`**

- Method creates a 'class' under the universe.
- It'll apply inheritance and store it in `classes` for further use from the `createObject` method.

**`CreateObject`**

- Creates an instance of a 'created' class.
- Attach an `objectID`.
- Link the `universe` where it's created.
- Reserve a space in `Containers` to store its data.
- Call init function (constructor).

Comment: It might help if you could describe what `universe.createClass()` is trying to do and why a function passed to it has to call such a hugely long thing like `this.universe.classes.Atom.prototype.fullName.call(this)` in the first place.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, check out the explanation @jfriend00. It should be more clear now.

Comment: Why would you register a class name with a framework and have to call `CreateObject()` with that name rather than just define a constructor function and call the constructor function to create a new object.  I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish in this framework that is advantageous over a normal constructor function and perhaps a single utility function for inheriting from something else.  And with ES6 on the way with an explicit syntax for new types of objects and transpilers already supporting ES6, why are you inventing something new and what are its advantages?

Comment: I need a way to declare classes modularly, each module will have an `universe` reference injected so they have access to createClass. The createObject call allow me to Notify the universe that a class has been instantiated.